# Loading XML in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I am trying to load a XML file using xmlLoad

```
<script LANGUAGE=JavaScript>
if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{

var xmlDoc= document.implementation.createDocument("","doc",null);  
xmlDoc.async=false;                   //make sure doc is fully loaded
loaded = xmlDoc.load("order.xml");

if(!loaded)
{ 
alert(“Error”);
}
else 
{
alert(xmlDoc.xml);
} 
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code? And how can I check if my code has been loaded or not?
Thanks!

Comment: What is going wrong? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, but I am not able to figure out if it has been loaded correctly or not! How can I check that.

Comment: I tried prinitng values from the XML file using childnodes and nodevalue, but dint get any output.

Comment: You are aware of your console? The browser functionality that shows you errors in javascript?

Comment: It is not showing any errors. I am not getting any output.

Comment: I guess I have to create an instance of XML parser, can anybody help me with that?

Comment: First try something, then update your question if you run into specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. Not sure if this is a pasting error, but the quotes within `alert(“Error”);` need to be straight quotes.
2. The `.xml` accessor only works in IE. You need `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc)` for other browsers.
3. For IE which odes not support `document.implementation.createDocument()`, you can conditionally use `var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");`.

This works in both IE and Firefox (with a well-formed "order.xml" file in the same directory as this HTML file):

```
var xmlDoc = document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument ? 
                document.implementation.createDocument("","doc",null) :
                new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async = false; //make sure doc is fully loaded
loaded = xmlDoc.load("order.xml");
if (!loaded) { 
    alert("Error");
}
else {
    alert(xmlDoc.xml || new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc));
}
```

Comment: I guess it is not required in Firefox.

Comment: It is compatible with Firefox API DOM>

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'load'